# Why is there an AttributeError report on the Character Class and animation_dir even though it is clearly defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I was adding animation frames into my game, I decidedly made specific folders and titles for each character (for example, character 1 will always look for its attacking frames in its own folder), and I made a variable for it called animation_dir. However, whenever I try to use it in my resources file for my game, it keeps reporting the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Character' has no attribute 'animation_dir'.

I have tried to add a type of instance called `charanimationdir = character.animation` but that didn't work at all.

resources file:

```py
ScrimitarAttackAnimation = Animation(Character.animation_dir + "SwordAttack", 4)
NevanStrumAnimation = Animation(Character.animation_dir + "Guitar Strum", 3)
ClawSlashAnimation = Animation(Character.animation_dir + "ClawSlash", 3)
```

Character Class:

```py
def __init__(self, nanimation_dir):
    self.animation_dir = nanimation_dir
```

With this, I expect to be able to change the current character graphics to the animated graphics presented above whenever certain actions are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've a class

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self, nanimation_dir):
        self.animation_dir = nanimation_dir
```

then the class `Character` doesn't have an attribute `animation_dir`.

But if you create an object of the class,

```py
mychar = Character("mydir")
```

then the object `mychar` has an attribute `mychar.animation_dir`

For a valid access to `Character.animation_dir`, you've to generate a class attribute

```py
class Character:
    animation_dir = "mydir"
```

See [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Comment: Thanks. This reminded me of a previous object I made called char that did the same thing presented here. Seriously, thank you very much!